# Assigning an Unicode to a wchar_t variable

Tags: c++, unicode

How to assign an `Unicode` such as character *Upwards Arrow*  to a `wchar_t` variable?

Comment: `wchar_t variable = L'\u1234';` (replace 1234 with the desired Unicode codepoint).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik is absolutely correct, that's the only sure-fire way to do it. And if you need to find the Unicode codepoint value, just Google it. For example, here's a page of arrows: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Unicode_chart_Arrows

Comment: Direct assignment of char literal won't work on Windows for codepoints U+10000 and above, since `wchar_t` is 16-bit. In such case you need to use surrogate pair that occupies two `wchar_t`.

Answer (score 0):

`wchar_t` might on Linux be 32 bits, but on Windows 16 bits, the UTF-16LE encoding, sometimes needing two wchar_t to store one Unicode code point.

UTF-16LE and UTF-16BE is not linear, has pairs that may not be split in two strings. And wchar_t is non-portable.

Hence better to use UTF-8 and `char`.

```
void append_utf8(string& s, uint cp) {
    if (cp < 0x80 && cp != 0) {
        // Let encode U+0 too (Modified UTF-8), as non-terminator?
        s.append(1, (char) cp);
    } else {
        char cpBytes[6];
        int bi = 0;
        int lastPrefix = 0xC0;
        int lastMask = 0x1F;
        for (;;) {
            int b = 0x80 | (cp & 0x3F);
            cpBytes[bi] = (char)b;
            ++bi;
            cp >>= 6;
            if ((cp & ~lastMask) == 0) {
                cpBytes[bi] = (char) (lastPrefix | cp);
                ++bi;
                break;
            }
            lastPrefix = 0x80 | (lastPrefix >> 1);
            lastMask >>= 1;
        }
        while (bi > 0) {
            --bi;
            s.append(1, cpBytes[bi]);
        }
    }
}

string s;
append_utf8(s, 0x2191): // For U+2191 up arrow.
append_utf8(s, 0x1F913): // For U+01F913 emoji nerd face.
```

***For wide chars (UTF-16) on Windows something like:***

```
void append_wch(std::wstring& s, uint cp) {
    if (cp < 0x10000) {
        s.append(1, (wchar_t) cp);
    } else {
        cp -= 0x10000;
        uint w = (cp >> 6) + 0xD800;
        s.append(1, (wchar_t) w);
        w = (cp & 0x3FF) + 0xDC00;
        s.append(1, (wchar_t) w);
    }
}
```

*(Mind I am tainted with Java influences.)*

Comment: The Windows API is UTF-16, so using UTF-8 on that platform requires lots of extra work. See http://utf8everywhere.org/

Comment: @MarkRansom Yes a Windows-only desktop development might be just what the OP wants. Thanks